# Pandas: How to apply a passed conditional operator to select rows in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I pass an operator as a parameter to a function and inside that function use that operator for selecting pandas rows?

```
# helper.py
def get_milage(operator, condition):
    return df[df.Milage <operator> condition]

# main.py
import operator
get_milage(operator.lt, 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need use [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html) in `()`, what is same like `operator.lt(column, value)`:

```
# helper.py
def get_milage(operator, condition):
    return df[operator(df.Milage, condition)]
```